# Переадресация ботов

Tags: redirect, php, бот

Так, есть страница **1.php**.

Не знаю, как реализовать, но хочется сделать редирект ботов.
Если боты (Googlebot, YandexBot, bingbot) зашли на страницу **1.php**, то сначала нужно посмотреть, если это боты, то оставить на этой же странице.

А если это не боты, то нужно подгрузить include  1test.php страницу заместо 1.php.

Нужно сделать это через php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вопрос стар как мир, и решений полно.**

```
function isBot ($ua) {

    $engines = array(
        array('Aport', 'Aport'),
        array('Google', 'Google'),
        array('msnbot', 'MSN'),
        array('Rambler', 'Rambler'),
        array('Yahoo', 'Yahoo'),
        array('Yandex', 'Yandex'),
        array('Aport', 'Aport robot'),
        array('Google', 'Google'),
        array('msnbot', 'MSN'),
        array('Rambler', 'Rambler'),
        array('Yahoo', 'Yahoo'),
        array('AbachoBOT', 'AbachoBOT'),
        array('accoona', 'Accoona'),
        array('AcoiRobot', 'AcoiRobot'),
        array('ASPSeek', 'ASPSeek'),
        array('CrocCrawler', 'CrocCrawler'),
        array('Dumbot', 'Dumbot'),
        array('FAST-WebCrawler', 'FAST-WebCrawler'),
        array('GeonaBot', 'GeonaBot'),
        array('Gigabot', 'Gigabot'),
        array('Lycos', 'Lycos spider'),
        array('MSRBOT', 'MSRBOT'),
        array('Scooter', 'Altavista robot'),
        array('AltaVista', 'Altavista robot'),
        array('WebAlta', 'WebAlta'),
        array('IDBot', 'ID-Search Bot'),
        array('eStyle', 'eStyle Bot'),
        array('Mail.Ru', 'Mail.Ru Bot'),
        array('Scrubby', 'Scrubby robot'),
        array('Yandex', 'Yandex')
    );

    foreach ($engines as $engine) {
        if (stristr($ua, $engine[0])) {
            return($engine[1]);
        }
    }
    return (false);
}

$isbot = isBot($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

if ($isbot) {
    echo 'А вы друг мой бот :)';
}
else {
    echo 'Bastian одобряет, вы чел! :)';
}
```

**Всё довольно просто :)**